# Why do user have not explain when they delete their question?

Tags: support

I delete for the 1. time a question, because the issue turn out as an hardware problem, so no way to resolve it with Unix/Linux. So i decide to delete it, and was surprised, that no explanation is necessary for that. 
Why is this so?

I hope I do not oversee some relevated info's.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Who would you explain it to?

Comment: I read for a few days http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/should-we-discourage-people-that-delete-their-question-after-they-receive-an-ans?s=11|0.3466   In my case there were no answers or comments.  I know from other forums only Mod's can delete questions. and it must be a good reason for that. So I was a little bit surprised and confused.  Sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize! I'm just trying to understand what your issue is :) As Michael explained below, you usually can delete your own posts with no difficulty. The exception is when that post has upvoted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can delete your own questions as long as they're unanswered, since nobody has posted any useful ideas yet. Once an answer on the question gets upvoted or accepted, or there's more than one answer, you can't delete the question anymore.

Comment: Is deleting possible with an excepted answer? I know I am a little bit snoopy. I was in a german Forum in Team. And there were no way that someone can delete his question  especially it was marked as solved. It   contradicts the idea of share.

Comment: thank's for clearing my mind Michael Mrozek :D

Comment: @Bahamut The complete list is in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/145982), under "When _can’t_ I delete my own post?". I updated this answer